# Apps Script: Use alias selected from dropdown list instead of alias of currently logged user

Tags: google-apps-script

We have a sidebar containing a simple html form to book appointments. It contains a dropdown list filled with email-addresses coming from a Google sheet. Anybody who wants to book an appointment must choose an email-address from that dropdown list. The selected email-address will then be used as the sender. **Example:** If I select *johndoe@example.com* from the dropdown list, then the sender for the booking confirmation will be *johndoe@example.com*.

And as you can imagine, *johndoe@example.com* is actually an alias that´s been created in John Doe´s Gmail-account. The same is true for all other email-addresses in that dropdown. In other words, each email-address in the dropdown list is an alias for a Gmail-account. We get all these aliases with this line of code:

```
var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
```

Now the problem is that the booking confirmation email will always be sent with the alias of the person currently logged/using the script instead of the email-address selected in the dropdown list. So, my question is: How can we make sure that the **email-address selected from the dropdown list** is used as the sender **instead of the alias of the person currently running the script?**

I´d appreciate any help or hint. And if you need more meat on the bones, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You literally can't. This would be a massive security issue as any email could be sent by anyone.

The only workaround I can think of would be to deploy a Web App for each user which sends an email on their behalf, and then calling the corresponding Web App URL using `UrlFetchApp` from the Sheet script, but this is really not something I would recommend. If you do decide to go down this route though, at the very least make sure that the contents of the email are not passed as `doGet(e)` parameters as it has severe potential for abuse.

Comment: Agreed: Deployment as web app is not an option. That´s why the booking system is running in sidebar. I´ll upvote/accept your answer. And thank you so much for the quick answer :)